# Why does Nietzsche affirm excellence so much?

Tags: nietzsche, aesthetics, metaethics

A recurring theme in Nietzsche's writings seems to be that humans should strive for excellence “the highest power and splendor possible to the type man”.

Im just wondering what it is about excellence that makes it the highest power/splendor.

Is it related to an aesthetic ideal, or represent WTP?

Comment: I'd link to his classical education & philology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arete

Answer (score 1):

I've done a recent dive into Nietzsche; both his early and late writings use this phrase rather frequently: "par excellence".  Nietzsche also admired French culture, where, in contrast, he looked down upon Germany's attempt to mimic the French in creating a culture of their own (I believe this passage I'm alluding to was either from *Ecce Homo* or *Untimely Meditations*.)

Here is a wiki link to the phrase: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/par_excellence

Nietzsche mentions in a passage from *Genealogy of Morals* how it might be important for philosophers and other great thinkers to look into the linguistics and etymological origins of morality; this might be why he emphasizes certain phrases, but doesn't insist on systematizing them (which I believe he downplays "systematizing" in *Human, All Too Human*.